# Quit app when pressed home button in android

Tags: android

I have an application which has background music in it. When I am pressing the home button, the background music is still playing. After that when I am clicking the recent apps button, to the right of the home button, and closing the app by swiping or pressing X, it is restarting as if the application is started again instead of closing the currently playing music. How do I solve this problem?

Where do I add the onTaskRemoved() method?

```
package com.example.dmacs.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by dmacs on 4/8/16.
 */
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by digen on 3/8/16.
 */
public class BackgroundAudioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        int mfile[] = new int[5];

        mfile[0]= R.raw.bgm1;
        mfile[1]= R.raw.bgm2;
        mfile[2]= R.raw.bgm3;
        mfile[3]= R.raw.bgm4;
        mfile[4]= R.raw.bgm5;

        Random random = new Random();
        int Low = 0;
        int High = mfile.length;
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;



        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, mfile[randomInt]);// raw/s.mp3
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand (Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            return START_STICKY;
        }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
    }



}
```

Comment: Try override onPause() method, it's called when home button pressed

Comment: When you swipe-to-right or press the X button in the recent apps, it closes the app. What you're getting is the correct behaviour. Unless you're asking why your Android Service got closed.

Comment: What I am asking is that the background music keeps playing on home button pressed and when swiped or pressed x to close while on recent apps , it starts all over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the Home button obviously won't stop a `Service` running in the background and swiping the app out of Recents won't work either, the OS will restart the `Service` because of `START_STICKY` returned from `onStartCommand()`.

You just have to stop the `Service` when appropriate (in `onPause()`, for example) by calling `stopService()`.

To stop your `Service` when your app is getting swiped out of Recents, you could just override `onTaskRemoved()` and call `stopSelf()` from there:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopSelf();
}
```